# flex3 autoupdater error

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air, auto-update

Dear all, I am working on flex3 and want to update my application by flex3 autoupdate. When my installed application runs, my checkUpdate function calls the autoUpdater code. It starts but when it reaches to 100%, it shows this error: "There was an error downloading the update. Error# 16824"

My mxml code is here http://tinypaste.com/92138b and server xml code is here http://tinypaste.com/e3792

Please guide me.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend for this one; it looks like you forgot to update the application descriptor version number in the updated version on the interweb.

http://dezeloper.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/adobe-air-updater-error-16824/

Comment: Many Thanks adamk. I got my problem solution.

Comment: But after successfully downloading update, again it is an error showing on pop up "This application cannot be installed because this installer has been mis-configured. Please contact the application author for assistance." Is there any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: I hate that message! :) It could be a number of things; if you find the adobe air installation log file at either C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Adobe\AIR\logs\Install.log for XP or C:\Users\<username>Appdata\Local\Adobe\AIR\logs\Install.log for Vista/7, there should be an error code in there.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to see your code as our work router blocks tinypaste.  That said, however, I can tell you that air updates done via the ApplicationUpdater class are all based upon the updater xml file that you create/copy-out-there, and the xml file used for the compiler that sets the filename, version, application ID, etc. (most of which is used for the exe-compiler/exe-wrapper that facilitates the "bridge" between the OS and your compiled actionscript code).  This link, might help: [dezeloper.wordpress.com](http://dezeloper.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/adobe-air-updater-error-16824/).

All-in-all keep debugging.  The ApplicationUpdater class is one that was relatively well-written and is pretty self-explainable... once you get past this bug, there are a couple more that might be a sync-the-xml-text pain-in-the-butt.  For example... I can tell you that in AIR 1.0 (and this may still be true in recent releases) if you made a change to your application xml file, and you're compiling from eclipse/flexBuilder/flashBuilder, you had to "project > clean" for those xml options to get picked up.

Best of luck,
Jeremy